# How can I format the layout of text in a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, string-formatting

I have some data in a string array, which I'd like to display in a textbox, formatted to appear in neat columns. The string values are of varying length, like names, so simply using "\t" doesn't give the desired effect.

Here is a sample string I am writing to the textbox from my array:

```
MyArray[thecount] = thearrayLine.GetValue(0).ToString() + " "
    + thearrayLine.GetValue(1).ToString() + ", "
    + thearrayLine.GetValue(2).ToString() + " "
    + myRemainingvalues + " "
    + thearrayLine.GetValue(4).ToString();
```

Comment: You might want to consider String.Join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want neat columns then you need to work with a layout that isn't dependent upon the font.  Meaning, you can't just throw it all into a textbox and hope that things consistently show up at the same point on the screen.

Instead, I see three possibilities:

1. Use a grid
2. Use an html table with various textboxes in columns of a row.
3. Use a floating div layout, again with various textboxes for the row.

Of those, I'd normally pick either #1 or #2.  I'd use #3 if my layout required the ability to fall down to other rows if the browser was too small.

Regardless, the font of a single textbox will determine the spacing of information contained within it.  You'll have to use a monospace font in order to even try and pull it off, but then you are still constrained by varying amounts of data per "column".  In short, I would never consider that approach as there are much better ones with easier control available.

Comment: If i was allowed to use a data grid that would be a lot more easier...but the end use specified a textbox.  but i found that padding the strings also worked.  used Stringvalue.PadRight(int, char) to solve it! i still accepted your answer Chris because using the data grid would be more logical...